# 7za.exe 9.20 cannot create archive with non english letters filename (utf-8)

Tags: windows, command-line, python, utf-8, 7za

I'm struggling to have 7za.exe create an archive including non latin characters.
The encoding is utf-8, characters are cyrillic.
I have a folder with the 4 files:

```
7za.exe privet.txt Кириллица.txt test.py
```

where the content of test.py is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

SOURCE_FILE = "Кириллица.txt"
DEST_ARCHIVE = "Кириллица.7z"

import subprocess

subprocess.call('7za a -bd -y privet.7z privet.txt', shell=True)

cmd_str = '7za a -bd -y %s %s' % (DEST_ARCHIVE, SOURCE_FILE)
subprocess.call(cmd_str, shell=True)
```

While I can create privet.7z from privet.txt, I cannot create Кириллица.7z from Кириллица.txt (an empty archive named ÐšÐ¸Ñ€Ð¸Ð»Ð»Ð¸Ñ†Ð°.7z is instead generated).

The output from 7za.exe is:

```
C:\BEPPE\STAMPARE\TEST_7za_cyrillic>python test.py
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning
Creating archive privet.7z
Everything is Ok
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning
ÐsÐ¸Ñ_Ð¸Ð»Ð»Ð¸Ñ┼Ð°.txt:  WARNING: Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
Creating archive ÐsÐ¸Ñ_Ð¸Ð»Ð»Ð¸Ñ┼Ð°.7z
WARNINGS for files:
ÐsÐ¸Ñ_Ð¸Ð»Ð»Ð¸Ñ┼Ð°.txt : Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
----------------
WARNING: Cannot find 1 file
```

Can anybody help me with this?
I also tried from a batch script test.bat with the following content:

```
7za.exe a -bd -y privet.7z privet.txt
7za.exe a -bd -y Кириллица.7z Кириллица.txt
```

but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Handling UTF-8 ([Unicode](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html), really) is *not* easy, it wouldn't surprise me in the least that handling of UTF-8 (or even non-ASCII) filenames just hasn't been done. The messed up name of the file created hints at serious problems in the handling of filenames (a compress/uncompress program is at the mercy of possibly malicious contents). I'd handle that as toxic materials, looking for a more robust compressing solution.

Comment: I also would like to avoid using this method but at the moment I really need to find a way because I have several documents compressed and password protected using this tool which on linux works great but on windows has this terrible limitation

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) (even the <900KB minimalist package will do)
2. Go to the `Settings / Preferences / New Document` tab and set the default **Encoding** to **UTF-8 without BOM**:

   [image: 1]
3. Open a new document and type the following command in it:

   ```
   cmd /u /c "chcp 65001 >nul && 7za.exe a -bd -y Кириллица.7z Кириллица.txt"
   ```
4. Ensure that Notepad++'s status bar says **ANSI as UTF-8** and save the document as a .BAT file:

   [image: 2]
5. Open a Command Prompt and run the batch file

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500) if you want the Command Prompt window to display Unicode characters.

Comment: On my Windows XP SP3 with italian language it doesn't work. I really tried many times with either version 920 and 922 but nothing :( Many tanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Any errors? Works fine in Win7 x64 (English). I'll see if I can find something that works in XP as well.

Comment: The errors are the same of the original post, empty archive created with gibberish letters and "cannot find one file". I'll try on Win7 x64 (italian) to see if it works there.